# React router change url change navlinks icon

Tags: reactjs, url, react-router, tailwind-css

I am using the React router version 5.2.0 and for example: when I am on the homepage, I want the home icon to change to the "active icon" ("acthome"), how should I proceed?
Thanks
The code is as follows:

```
            <li>
            <NavLink activeClassName="!text-white " to={"/"} href ="#" exact className="h-10 flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-link hover:text-white px-4 gap-4">
                <span className='transition-colors'>
                    <Icon name="home"/>
                </span>
                <span className='transition-colors hidden'>
                    <Icon name="acthome"/>
                </span>
                Ana sayfa
            </NavLink>
        </li>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`this.props.location.pathname` is a react-router feature](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/location), represent where the app is now

```
<NavLink activeClassName="!text-white " to={"/"} href ="#" exact className="h-10 flex items-center text-sm font-bold text-link hover:text-white px-4 gap-4">
    {this.props.location.pathname !== '/' ?
            <span className='transition-colors'>
                <Icon name="home"/>
            </span>
            :
            <span className='transition-colors'>
                <Icon name="acthome"/>
            </span>
    }
    Ana sayfa
</NavLink>
```

Comment: First of all, thanks, I have one more problem, the icon I changed is not visible without refreshing the page, I wonder how can I solve it?

Comment: It should work without reload, try to remove href attribute from your NavLink component, as additional option you can use activeClassName and toggle specific child div

Comment: I will try remove href attribute from your NavLink component but dont work if i refrehs page dont change new icon